# to_datetime: "unconverted data remains" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date

I have the following dataframe, scraped from this [url](https://www.borsaitaliana.it/borsa/derivati/ftse-mib-div-futures/lista.html?lang=en):

```
             Name  Closing
0  December 2021     873.0
1      June 2022     662.0
2  December 2022     970.0
3      June 2023     653.0
4  December 2023     951.0
5  December 2024     927.0
6  December 2025     882.0
```

Now I want to convert the 'Name' column to datetime:

```
df['Name']= pd.to_datetime(df['Name'], format='%B %Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but I get the following ValueError: "unconverted data remains:   "

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Running your code produces formatted date strings. Is this your original dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, looking at your dataframe, seems that there is empty space after the year `" "`. Try `str.strip` first:

```py
df["Name"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Name"].str.strip(), format="%B %Y").dt.strftime(
    "%Y-%m-%d"
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Name  Closing
0  2021-12-01    873.0
1  2022-06-01    662.0
2  2022-12-01    970.0
3  2023-06-01    653.0
4  2023-12-01    951.0
5  2024-12-01    927.0
6  2025-12-01    882.0
```